# JBoss AS 7 how to count the free beans in the pool

Tags: jboss7.x

I'd like to know if there is a metric available through CLI which returns the amount of SLSF available in the EJB pool ? 
Thanks
max

Answer (score 1):

first you need to enable statistics for ejb's
you do that by running command:

> /subsystem=ejb3:write-attribute(name=enable-statistics, value=true)

then you can go to:

> /deployment=/subsystem=ejb3/stateless-session-bean=

and you will be able to see all the statistics for this SLSB

also note that if you are deploying war or ear, path would be something like

> /deployment=/subdeployment=/subsystem=ejb3/...